# SQL Union Replacement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table contacts and in that table there is a contact level and levelID.  So a contact can be Admin, Assistant, friend etc.  Each one of these levels has its own table so right now to get all the contacts and the information I have a query with a series of levels each with their own query for example

```
SELECT  Admin.AdminDescripiton, Contact.ContactTypeID,  Contact.LevelID,  Contact.FundID, etc.
FROM    Contact  INNER JOIN Admin ON Contact.LevelID = Admin.AdminID
WHERE   (Contact.LevelID = 1)

UNION

SELECT  Assistant.AssistantDescripiton, Contact.ContactTypeID, Contact.LevelID,Contact.FundID, etc.
FROM Contact
     INNER JOIN Assistant ON Contact.LevelID = Assistant. AssistantID
WHERE
     (Contact.LevelID = 2)

UNION

SELECT  Friend.FriendDescripiton, etc   
FROM Contact
     INNER JOIN Friend ON Contact.LevelID = Friend. FriendID
WHERE
     (Contact.LevelID = 3)
```

It there a way to put this into a case statement or some other  join type that could replace the unions with on just one select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not completely clear what your tables and data looks like but maybe you could use left joins like this:

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(AdminDescripiton, AssistantDescripiton, FriendDescripiton) AS Description
    , c.ContactTypeID
    , c.FundID
    , c.LevelID
FROM contact c
LEFT JOIN Admin ON c.LevelID = Admin.AdminID AND (c.LevelID = 1)
LEFT JOIN Assistant ON c.LevelID = Assistant.AssistantID AND (c.LevelID = 2)
LEFT JOIN Friend ON c.LevelID = Friend.FriendID AND (c.LevelID = 3)
```

The `coalesce` operator returns the first non-null value from it's arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a LEFT JOIN might work.

```
SELECT Assistant.AssistantDescripiton, Contact.ContactTypeID, Contact.LevelID, Contact.FundID, ...
FROM Contact
LEFT JOIN ADMIN  ON Contact.LevelID = ADMIN.AdminID
                AND Contact.LevelID = 1
LEFT JOIN Assistant ON Contact.LevelID = Assistant.AssistantID
                    AND Contact.LevelID = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I was going to say nearly the same thing as jpw did but I was using a case statement rather than the coalesce method.  I think his is cleaner.